# I can't vertical align a logo on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, alignment, graphical-logo

I spend the last two days trying to vertical align a logo in a website done with wordpress.

Here's the link: www.contidosdixitais.com

Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Tried with

```
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 0;
```

and more but nothing works.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code? Most of us aren't going to go to your website and trawl through the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to that div up top with the 'title-area' class, try:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(50%);
transform: translateY(50%);
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

The only way to move it down is adding margin-top: 35px;
But I know that this is not the correct way.

Comment: Sorry, try this: -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(50%);
transform: translateY(50%);

Comment: Yes! now it's working. Now I have to work with the tablet and mobile version to remove this translate when you're using a phone or tablet, but thanks so much!